# Reading JSON results in swedish characters as question marks

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ascii, geojson

I'm trying to read a GeoJSON file through jquery and the file includes some information written in Swedish. When I later try to send these Swedish words through an AJAX call, the strings end up with a question mark instead of the non ASCII-characters. How can I make sure that I can read the GeoJSON file and get the content represented in a correct way regarding the the Swedish characters?

We just read the file like this and then the text is not displayed correctly. Later we send it through the back end with Ajax the text is supposed to be used for querying the database and results in error.

```
 $.getJSON(myJSONfile.json', function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
    }
```

Characters like "ä" will look like �.

Comment: Add code example here to more understanding.

Comment: Is every file/data-source you use here (PHP, JS, XML, your DB-table) encoded in UTF8? Compare!

Comment: ... and are you using `charset=utf-8` for all requests/responses?

Comment: Filter the data on server site file.